# Как подключить media файлы django при DEBUG = False?

Tags: django

Какой url к медиа-файлам должен быть, если `DEBUG = False`? Сейчас в доках нашёл

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Но это для отладки (`DEBUG = False`)

Также в settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: Поставить nginx перед джангой

Comment: @andreymal Сайт уже развёрнут на хостинге python anywhere

Comment: А у pythonanywhere про это в справке есть https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles

Answer (score 1):

Django не предназначен для отдачи статики в продуктиве. В [документации говорится](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files):

> Django doesn’t serve files itself; it leaves that job to whichever Web server you choose.

Для этих целей обычно выбирают nginx или apache.

Comment: Автор не спрашивал, предназначен или нет, автор спрашивал - как сделать :) К тому же сделать можно (но как - не расскажу, не хочу учить плохому)

Comment: Простите, но если автор спрашивает как, а как - это неправильно, то лучше я покажу правильное направление.

Comment: всё, разобрался